# Live Edit on WebStorm 7

Tags: html, web, webstorm

I have download JB IDE support in my chrome but it does not work.When I change the html file but does not change in chrome.who can tell me why?

Comment: Live Edit only works during debug session - did you start it? See http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Live+Edit for some hints. Also, what is your Chrome version?

Comment: OK,it's working when i change the Chrome version.Thanks!

Comment: then it should be [WEB-12418](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12418). Problem is caused by Chrome API changes, the only workaround for WebStorm 7 is downgrading Chrome to v.36.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging/Live Edit with WebStorm 7.* and 8.* (PHPStorm 7.*, Idea 12.*) don't work when using Chrome 37.* or higher. Problems are caused by Chrome API changes. The issue is fixed in [WebStorm 9 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP)

Answer (score 0):

in chrome go to `chrome://flags/`
and enable the flag `Enable Silent Debugging`